# bootstrap 3 modal - javascript available multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 modal dialogs with remote sources.
My Problem is that I use external JavaScript and script blocks in those remote sources. When I open and Close a modal Dialog and then reopen it, the JavaScript is loaded twice.

How can I suppress from loading the same JavaScript file again when reopening the modal Dialog? Or how can I destroy the loaded JavaScript when closing the Dialog?

**JavaScript**:

```js
$(function() {
    $('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
        if(remote) {
            $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```html
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" 
   data-load-remote="http://localhost/dashboard/myprices"
   data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">My Salon (Preview)</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another `data-` attribute to check whether it's loaded or not:

Add `isloaded="false"` to your anchor tag like so:

```html
<a data-isloaded="false" href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" 
   data-load-remote="http://localhost/dashboard/myprices" 
   data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">My Salon (Preview)</a>
```

Then you can check if it's been loaded using `$this.data('isloaded')`.  If it has, get out of there, if not, load it and set the flag like so: `$this.data('isloaded', true)`.

Here's some JavaScript

```js
$(function() {
    $('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
        if (!$this.data('isloaded')) {
            if(remote) {
                $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
                $this.data('isloaded', true)
            }
        }
    });
});
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/6maV8/)

---

**UPDATE** for clarification based on comment

From the HTML5 spec on [**custom data attributes**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):

> Every *HTML element* may have any number of *custom data attributes* specified, with any value.

i.e. There is no predefined `data-isloaded`, the same as there is no predefined `data-load-remote`.  You could just as easily call it `data-kylePromisesTheValueIsLoaded`.  As long as
that's the string you pass to the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method, then it will read / write the value for that attribute.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i wasn't Aware of the data-isloaded Attribute!

But i forgot one Point to mention.

I have two different remote sources, which include the same external js-file! I can't embed the external js in the main page (so that it is available for both remote sources) cause of Performance reasons!

is there a possibility to destroy the loaded JavaScript? or remove it from the DOM?

thanks!